# Gson does not correctly serialize LocalDate

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am writing an android application, where I want to serialize instances of this [`Anime.java`](https://github.com/SandroHc/reactive-jikan/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sandrohc/jikan/model/anime/Anime.java) class. Its superclass [`AnimeBase.java`](https://github.com/SandroHc/reactive-jikan/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sandrohc/jikan/model/anime/AnimeBase.java) has a field called `aired`, which is of the type [`DateRange`](https://github.com/SandroHc/reactive-jikan/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sandrohc/jikan/model/DateRange.java). This `DateRange` contains two fields:

```
public LocalDate from;
public LocalDate to;
```

The serialization is very straight-forward (using gson) like this:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(obj);
```

However, in my result, the `from` and `to` fields are always empty like here:

```
// ...
"trailer_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SlNpRThS9t8?enablejsapi\u003d1\u0026wmode\u003dopaque\u0026autoplay\u003d1",
"aired": {
  "from": {}
},
"episodes": 16,
// ...
```

Here, `to` was null, so it is missing (and that is okay).

Why is gson not serializing these two `LocalDate`s? Does it have something to do with the `DateRange`s setter & getter (which are a bit unusual, taking a `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `LocalDate`)?

Since these classes stem from a 3rd-party library, is there a good way for me to handle this without duplicating all the model classes in my own application for serializing/deserializing them?

Comment: The "fun" aspect of this problem, this only occurs when the buildType is declared as `debuggable true`. When declared as `debuggable false` everything works fine to us.
I just dig a bit into it and the source of this problem seems to be that Gson is using `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` by default and the "reflection part" is not working properly.
`java.time.LocalDate.class.getDeclaredFields()` does not return any non-static fields and therefore the serialized value is empty. Why this is working in non-debuggable mode isn't yet clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers
There are serializers for LocalDate objects.

If you choose to create your own serializer:

```java
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<LocalDate>(){}.getType(), new LocalDateConverter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
...

public class LocalDateConverter implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {
  public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(src));
  }

  public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(json.getAsString(), LocalDate::from);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could now find the source of this problem.

Starting in Android 9, Google added something called "[Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](http://%20https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)" where they restrict the access to not publicly documented SDK interfaces in the Android dalvik runtime.

Since Gson by default uses the `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` which itself looks for serializable fields in the object to be serialized it heavily depends on Reflection.

Google has documented this behaviour, that the used function `Class.getDeclaredFields()` which is used by `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` do return only public accessible Fields, or more concrete, only fields which are whitelisted by Google.
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#results-of-keeping-non-sdk

In the referenced documentation, Google explicitly states the java.time.LocalDate fields as greylisted:

```
Ljava/time/LocalDate;->day:S,greylist-max-o
```

I am not sure why this access is still working in release mode and the behaviour only is present when the build is `debuggable` but I suppose this is something which will be removed in future Android versions too.

Because of this we added our own backwards-compatible Serializer (which is similar to the one of @k1r0, but still works with previously serialized values):

```kotlin
class LocalDateJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    override fun serialize(src: LocalDate, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
        return JsonObject().also {
            it.addProperty("year", src.year)
            it.addProperty("month", src.monthValue)
            it.addProperty("day", src.dayOfMonth)
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): LocalDate {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        return LocalDate.of(jsonObject["year"].asInt, jsonObject["month"].asInt, jsonObject["day"].asInt)
    }

}
```